# How can I make a single column table flow to the right in html/css?

Tags: html, css

I have a single column table that dynamically adds and removes values.  Because the size of the screen we are displaying it on is not tall, I wanted the rows to move to the right.  For example:

This is a table that fits on the screen

```
 ____________
|______1_____|
|______2_____|
|______3_____|
```

This is a table that doesn't fit on the screen

```
 ________________________
|______1_____|_____4_____|
|______2_____|_____5_____|
|______3_____|
```

Thanks in advance, here is how the table looks like.

```
<table id="values_table" class="table table-bordered panel">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th><strong>Value</strong></th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="font-color3">
      <td data="1"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="font-color3">
      <td data="2"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="font-color3">
      <td data="3"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="font-color3">
      <td data="4"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="font-color3">
      <td data="5"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Its not clear to understand, You want the output to be like the second image ?

Comment: @JonesVinothJoseph sorry about that. I meant I want the table to extend to the right when there is more rows instead of going off the screen.

Comment: a horizontal scroll-able page is what you mean ?

Comment: @JonesVinothJoseph yes.

Comment: you can try to use bootstrap class col-lg and col-sm as per your screen size

Answer (score 0):

Try this, jsut few tricks with `display: flex;`

```css
tbody {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 80px;
}
tr {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table id="values_table" class="table table-bordered panel">
  <tbody>

    <tr class="font-color3">
      <td data="1">1</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="font-color3">
      <td data="2">2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="font-color3">
      <td data="3">3</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="font-color3">
      <td data="4">4</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="font-color3">
      <td data="5">5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```